# European alternative for mobile cloud testing with Calabash and Appium

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, appium, cloud-hosting, calabash

are there any European alternatives for mobile Calabash tests in the cloud?

I only found the following US companies, which because of privacy concerns are no alternative for my current employer:

- [xamarin.com](http://xamarin.com/)
- [appthwack.com](https://appthwack.com/)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the issue that Xamarin is an american company or is it related to location of their actual test lab? I don't know where their test lab is at, but at least they have an office in Aarhus, Denmark. And LessPainful that they acquired are from Denmark so it might be that Test Cloud is located in Denmark. But if that would change things you can ask their support team about that info.

Comment: A location in Europe would be a plus, but even better would be if it isn't a US owned company. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at Xamarin on Xamarin Test Cloud. Presently the data center is located in Denmark although we're planning out multiple data centers.

Comment: Thanks for this update. Is the Denmark subsidiary  a standalone legal entity?

Comment: Yes. Xamarin Denmark ApS. The CVR number is 33644949